# Lowering Freezing Point of Amines

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is most efficient method of lowering freezing point of amines without greatly effecting properties? Method must involve incorporating an additive at small percentage.

Comment: Protonate the amine?

Comment: Hmm... That's backward, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Add another amine. It is better to choose an amine with just few more carbons.

Comment: Can I use a plastisizer or even something like salt similar to reducing freezing point in water.

Comment: May be there is some additive that can help inihibit mechanism that promotes freezing?

Comment: If another amine is added then how much more needs to be added to inhibit the freezing? If its too high an amount then properties could be effected. Essentially I have a problem that this amine crystallises or freezes below a certain temperature and I then have to warm which is time consuming.

Comment: What about adding dimethylformamide?

Comment: Sounds like you're performing a reaction or preparation neat. Without knowing anything else, I would think about the more inert solvents, such as an ether, MTBE? As little as 1-4% (sometimes less) of an additive can affect melting points. e.g. I have used 4% NMP in sulfolane to keep the latter at liquid at 20 degrees C. Just experiment!